# Cannot find name System angular 2 webpack 2

Tags: angular, webpack-2

I changed my async routes loading to to look like this.

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { RoleModel, ConfigurationResolverService } from '../shared/services';

import { UnitMaintenancePage } from '../unit-maintenance.page/unit-maintenance.page'; import { TimeEntryPage } from '../time-entry.page/time-entry.page'; import { LayoutMainPage } from './layout-main.page'; import { DashboardPage } from '../dashboard.page/dashboard.page'; import { PayTypesPage } from '../pay-types.page/pay-types.page'; import { LayoutMainAuthGuardService } from './layout-main-auth-guard.service';

/**   * Here are the application routes   */

export const layoutMainRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: LayoutMainPage,
        canActivate: [LayoutMainAuthGuardService],
        data: { roles: [RoleModel.ADMIN] },
        // canActivate: [ActivateRouteGuardService],
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                loadChildren: () => System.import('../dashboard.page/dashboard.module').then(module => module['DashboardModule'])
            },
            {
                path: 'holiday-maintenance',
                loadChildren: () => System.import('../holiday-maintenance.page/holiday-maintenance.module').then(module
=> module['HolidayMaintenanceModule'])
            },
            {
                path: 'unit-maintenance',
                loadChildren: () => System.import('../unit-maintenance.page/unit-maintenance.module').then(module
=> module['UnitMaintenanceModule'])
            },
            {
                path: 'time-entry',
                loadChildren: () => System.import('../time-entry.page/time-entry.module').then(module => module['TimeEntryModule'])
            },
            {
                path: 'shift-maintenance',
                loadChildren: () => System.import('../shift-maintenance.page/shift-maintenance.module').then(module
=> module['ShiftMaintenanceModule'])
            },
            {
                path: 'pay-types',
                loadChildren: () => System.import('../pay-types.page/pay-types.module').then(module => module['PayTypesModule'])
            },
            {
                path: 'category-maintenance',
                loadChildren: () => System.import('../category-maintenance.page/category-maintenance.module').then(module
=> module['CategoryMaintenanceModule'])
            },
            {
                path: 'employee-maintenance',
                loadChildren: () => System.import('../employee-maintenance.page/employee-maintenance.module').then(module
=> module['EmployeeMaintenanceModule'])
            },
            {
                path: 'employee-overrides',
                loadChildren: () => System.import('../employee-overrides.page/employee-overrides.module').then(module
=> module['EmployeeOverridesModule'])
            },
            {
                path: 'timekeeper-maintenance',
                loadChildren: () => System.import('../timekeeper.page/timekeeper.module').then(module => module['TimekeeperMaintenanceModule'])
            },
            {
                path: 'sub-category',
                loadChildren: () => System.import('../sub-category.page/sub-category.module').then(module
=> module['SubCategoryModule'])
            },
            {
                path: 'function-maintenance',
                loadChildren: () => System.import('../function-maintenance.page/function-maintenance.module').then(module
=> module['FunctionMaintenanceModule'])
            }
        ]
    } ];
```

Webpack suggested this but I still get the error on checking.

```
[at-loader] Checking finished with 12 errors
Error in bail mode: [at-loader] src\app\layout-main.page\layout-main.routes.ts:26:37
    Cannot find name 'System'.
```

I installed `@types/systemjs` but it doesn't seem to have an effect on it does anyone know from where is this problem ?

Comment: As far as I know, System should be SystemJS. you can take a look into `@types/systemjs` and you will find out, how it's written

Comment: Try add <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script> to index.html

Comment: But the build works, and i don't use system js at all I changed it like this because router-loader suggested it and it still works I don't understand why I get this error. Event if I let the routes to be inported like this '../function-maintenance.page/function-maintenance.module#FunctionMaintenanceModule' I get that error

Comment: I tryed to change it to SystemJS butI et the same error

Comment: may be you want to try this first https://github.com/brandonroberts/angular-router-loader

Comment: I switched from it to the other route loader, I will post an answer for the question tomorrow, maybe someone can explain to me why it works now.

Answer (score 0):

> I deleted my typings.json and typings folder and after that
>   reinstalled everything. Webpack works now but I don't understand why
>   the typings folder had conflicts with the configuration, can anyone
>   explain why ?